# Go in VSCode not signalling the lack of comment in public functions

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, golint

I have installed Go and the VSCode extensions.

I am using **staticcheck** as linter but I would like also to run the style checks provided by **golint**.

When I look for the **go.lint** settings in VSCode, I see that I can specify either **staticcheck** or **golint** as Lint tool.

Even **golangci-lint** does not seem to run **golint** style checks.

Any suggestion on how to run both **staticcheck** AND **golint** any time a file is saved?

Comment: staticceck is static code analysis not a style linter. If you want to use golint do so and if you want to do staticcheck do so; they have nothing in common except they both are for Go. What is your question?

Comment: @Volker What I would like to achieve is to have both style linting and **staticheck** validations run at the same time. With VSCode settings, and VSCode extension installed, I can specify either **golint** or **staticheck** as Lint tool. Even **golangci-lint** does not seem to run **golint** style checks. I have updated the question hopint this is more clear.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: due to question changes, no longer answers the question

In VS Code settings, under Go extension, find 'Lint Flags' and add flag:

```
-checks=all
```

or you can select which checks to enforce, the list is here: https://staticcheck.io/docs/checks

After saving the source file (depending on your vs code settings, but in most cases, it will trigger the linter), you should be able to see the error

Comment: On save I actually trigger the linter. The point is that it is either **golint** or **staticheck**, not both, which is what I am looking for.

Comment: I do not think you can set multiple linters in the go extension

Comment: There is no reason you should run `golint` - that's deprecated&unmaintained and doesn't work well with go module. `staticcheck` or `golangci-lint` already include golint-style checks but you need to configure to enable them if necessary.

Comment: @BartekPacia the question has changed since answering, I will add a note

Comment: I also liked that warning "The comment on the exported function F must be of the form...", but I haven't seen them in a month or so. I think it got removed – how to get it back?